# Use Javascript Client Library to use Calendar api v3 from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a chrome extension that can add Google calendar events to a person's google Calendar (create one appointment for irregular reoccuring dates).

To do this I am using oauth 2.0 and I would like to use the javascript Client library to make the required calls.

Whenever I try to use the gapi object, I will receive the error that the object is undefined.

Does anyone have a good example on how to use the javascript client library in a chrome extension, or a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth This is the link I used to get it working.  Hint: you need to change the scope to work with calendar api.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the link you suggest uses oauth1.0 where I am working with oauth2.0 (the new standard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using chrome.identity https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity

Comment: I am already using the identity api to get the token. I would like to use the javascript client library to make the required calls to create calendar appointments. If you have a better alternative, I would be happy to read it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe the Google library is supported for Chrome extensions due to Content Security Policy. I use simple XMLHttpRequest, via this library http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2011/12/teach-your-xmlhttprequest-some-json/#more-115 which gives a JSONHttpRequest object, to call the Google REST APIs.