# How extension can interact directly with google calendar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been developing an extension that has ability to interact with Google calendar. For example, when I create event on gg cal, it'll send back data to my server at the same time, or I want to inject my html code to creating event screen, capture gg calendar events.. So the question is: is there any kind of library that support those actions (something like inboxsdk for Gmail) ?

Comment: I don't now about any SDKs, but you can try [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API to catch create & delete events and [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) + code injecting to change a webpage

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Google APIs with Chrome extension. You can use [**`chrome.identity`**](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity) to get OAuth2 access tokens. Then use XMLHttpRequest to call the Google REST APIs as stated in this related SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21940072/5995040) and the rest will be your own implementation.

Try checking this [github](https://github.com/nanosun/gcalquickadd-chrome) - which lets you quick add an event to Google Calendar. This sample uses OAuth 2.0 and XMLHttpRequest to call Calendar API.